# Python dict-how to send both default and add user input value

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have requirement to set the default value if the tag is None ,else need to keep the default value and add user input tag for AWS Secret Manager Create secrets.

Here is the current code-

```
def create_secret(self, secret_name, secret_value, tags_dict=None):
    default_tag = [{"Key": "applicationid", "Value": "AP149393"}]
    if tags_dict is None:
        tags_dict = default_tag
    create_response = {}
    for region, client in self.client.items():
        try:
            create_secret = {"Name": secret_name}
            if isinstance(secret_value, str):
                create_secret["SecretString"] = secret_value
            elif isinstance(secret_value, bytes):
                create_secret["SecretBinary"] = secret_value
            logging.info(f'Creating secret {secret_name} in the {region} region')
            create_response = client.create_secret(**create_secret, Tags=tags_dict)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(f'Could not create a secret {secret_name} in the {region} region. Error: {e}')
    return create_response
```

I have tried to parse with else condition and add `tags_dict = {default_tag, tags_dict}` . this has issue with the datatype being sent.

```py
  if tags_dict is not None:
      tags_dict = tags_dict, default_tag
  else:
      tags_dict = default_tag
  #tags_dict = tags_dict if tags_dict is not None else default_tag
```

Comment: What you have now seems ok. Can you elaborate on what " has issue with the datatype" means.

Comment: i would like to change this, for tag_dict to take both default_tag and user input.Currently default_tag is created only when the tag_dict is None and if the user provides a value,then only input data is created without default value. i want this to be create both(default_tag + input value).

Comment: `default_tag` isn't a dict, it's a list of dictionaries. Assuming `tag_dict` is also a list of dictionaries, you should be able to combine lists like `combined = tag_list1 + tag_list2` ...